# Prove if f(n) = O(g(n)), f (n) + g(n) = Ω(g(n)).

Tags: algorithms

Use the formal definition of Big-Oh to prove that if f (n) and g(n) are nonnegative functions such that f (n) = O(g(n)), f (n) + g(n) = Ω(g(n)).

By the definition of Big-Oh:

If f(n)  and g(n) are non-negative functions such that f(n)  = O(g(n)) there must be positive constants c and n_0 such that 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ c(g(n))  for all n ≥ n_0.

My approach so far:
If 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ c(g(n)) and f(n) and g(n) are non-negative functions we know c(g(n)  ≤ c( f(n) + g(n) ) we can rewrite the original inequality as:

0 ≤ f(n) ≤ c( (f(n) + g(n) )

0 ≤ (1/c)f(n) ≤ f(n) + g(n)

But I've reached a dead end here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from
$$0 \le f(n) \le \text{c}g(n)~~\text{for all $n\ge n_0$}$$ 
we have
$$f(n) \ge 0, ~\text{c}g(n) \ge 0 \implies \text{c}g(n) \le \text{c}(f(n)+g(n))~~\text{for all $n\ge n_0$}$$
and as $c$ is a positive constant, we can divide by $c$ to form
$$f(n)+g(n)\ge 1*g(n)~~\text{for all $n\ge n_0$}$$

Comment: I had just come up with since () ≥ 0 and () ≥ 0 we can say () ≤ ()+(). Surely there is a c, namely 0 < c ≤ 1, such that c() ≤ (). Therefore we can say there is a c > 0 such that c() ≤ ()+().  Does this work as well?

Comment: You need to find a positive $c>0$ such that $f(n)+g(n) \ge cg(n)$.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally hit the enter button before finishing my reply

Comment: The analysis in the comment works because $cg(n) \ge 0$ and $c>0$ implies that $g(n)\geq 0$. You would want to mention for all $n\geq n_0$ at every step.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is much appreciated!